# Download cuda headers on laptop without GPU

Tags: cuda

I'd like to write cuda kernels on my laptop without GPU, in vscode (Ubuntu 21.04). Is it possible to just download all the headers and source files somewhere, without the need of installing the full CUDA Toolkit?

That way I can still enjoy some autocompletion, but do not have to install the entire toolkit that won't function anyway as I don't have a GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can download the headers from [Nvidia's GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/cudart) and add the path into `includePath` in your [VSCode project C/C++ settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) the same way you would add `include` directory of CUDA Toolkit installation.

Below Linux example of `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` where you would replace `/usr/local/cuda-11.3/include` with your path to the downloaded headers. If you are targeting specific device or architecture, then definining e.g. `__CUDA_ARCH__=750` (for CUDA Compute capability 7.5) will help Intellisense pick correct set of CUDA intrinsic functions that will be available on those devices.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/cuda-11.3/include"
            ],
            "defines": ["__CUDA_ARCH__=750"],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

With the setup above, [NVIDIA Nsight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NVIDIA.nsight-vscode-edition) should work for syntax highlighting without CUDA Toolkit installation (not tested) with `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.cu": "cuda-cpp",
        "*.cuh": "cuda-cpp"
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, associate your CUDA kernel source files with C++ syntax highlighting in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.cu": "cpp",
        "*.cuh": "cpp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Except [cudart](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/cudart), [nvcc](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/nvcc) (for `crt/*` headers) and [cccl](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/cccl) (for `nv/*`, `cuda/*` etc. headers) should be included as well.

Answer (score 1):

## For Windows users

Minimum working example on Windows (and [VSBT](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)):

Download [cudart](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/cudart), [nvcc](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/nvcc) (`"crt/*"`) and [cccl](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/headers/cuda-individual/cccl) (`<nv/*>`, `<cuda/*>` etc.) and place them in `~/include`:

```
include
- cccl
- cudart
- nvcc
```

(I believe cccl and nvcc are necessary on Linux as well.)

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/${env:USERNAME}/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "__CUDACC__",
                "__CUDA_ARCH__=800"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

(I believe `__CUDACC__` is necessary on Linux too.)